# Postgresql Using max function in trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql

--Problem is: i have more companies and i want to make id_shutter "autoincrement" from 1 for each company  (id_company and id_shutter are composite PK)

```
 CREATE FUNCTION insert_shutter() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $insert_shutter$
BEGIN
    IF exists(select 1 from shutter where id_company=new.id_company) then
    SELECT MAX(id_shutter) INTO new.id_shutter FROM shutter where id_company=new.id_company;
    new.id_shutter:=id_shutter+1;
    ELSE
    new.id_shutter=1;
    end if;
        RETURN NEW;

END;
$insert_shutter$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_shutter 
    BEFORE INSERT ON shutter
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_shutter();
```

Answer (score 2):

sorry i found out, i cant use: new.id_shutter:=id_shutter+1;
i made  SELECT MAX(id_shutter)+1 INTO new.id_shutter FROM shutter where id_company=new.id_company;

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally this is necessary.  But really, it is much easier to add a `serial` column to the table (let's call it `ShutterId`) and then do the calculation when you retrieve the data:

```
select s.*, row_number() over (partition by company order by id) as CompanyShutterSequence
from shutter s;
```

Also, calling something an `id` that will take on duplicated values is misleading.